# FORM POST with in a javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii, yii-events

I have a form like this..

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'price-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
)); ?>
```

And a submit buttom like this..

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save Changes', array('name' => 'Edit','id'=>'submit''));?>
```

Jquery and javascrippt functions are:

```
function checkSum()
{
    //alert();
    if(false)
    {
        alert('Please Enter valid credintals !');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //i have to post my form, how can i achieve this 
        where where url goes like this
        controllerName/actionName?id=something
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        checkSum();
    });
});
```

I have to catch my url segment id later in the controller by form post method where i have to handle the `id = something`
Help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work

```
<?php echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Save Changes',array('onclick'=>'return checkSum();'));?>
```

and it is not necessary to use jquery.